# Cloudant multi-database query

Tags: cloudant, database, nosql

So I have criteria which looks like this:

```
{
    _id: '1234',
    name: 'Weight',
    states: [{
        _id: '5678',
        name: 'Heavy',
        filters: [{
            type: 'field',
            operator: '>',
            field: 'weightWithBattery',
            expression: '100'
        }]
    }, {
        _id: '91011',
        name: 'Light',
        filters: [{
            type: 'field',
            operator: '<',
            field: 'weightWithBattery',
            expression: '101'
        }]
    }]
}
```

This is just one example, I have quite a few.
the database that contains these documents is aptly named **criteria**.

Now I wish to create a new database called **persona** which will have documents that look something like this:

```
{
    name: 'Weekender',
    states: [91011]
}
```

So in this case, the **weekender** requires **light** items. The states reference the **state** within the **criteria**.
The problem I have is that I am really new to cloudant, so I have no idea how to set that up (of even if I should be using a separate database) and I have no idea how to build a query so that if I get a **persona** I want it to pull in all **states** assigned to it (like a view I guess).

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple options here. First of all, a view cannot combine data across different databases. So, one option that will *NOT* work is having a single view with two databases.

I think the most straight forward way of doing this is to use two databases and make two calls. The first call would retrieve the `persona`. The second call would use the `states` array on the `persona` object to retrieve states from the `criteria` database. The second call would look something like this:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "_id": { "$gt": null },
    "states": {
      "$elemMatch" : {
        "_id": {"$in": ["91011","xyz"] }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "_id",
    "_rev",
    "states"
  ]
}
```

Note: this will return the _id of the `criteria` and **all** of the criteria's states, like so:

```
{
  "_id": "1234",
  "_rev": "2-c61f92414e9f016e9fae97a9c1214dc5",
  "states": [
    {
      "_id": "5678",
      "name": "Heavy",
      "filters": [{
        "type": "field",
        "operator": ">",
         "field": "weightWithBattery",
         "expression": "100"
      }]
    },
    {
      "_id": "91011",
      "name": "Light",
      "filters": [{
        "type": "field",
        "operator": "<",
        "field": "weightWithBattery",
        "expression": "101"
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

So, in code, you would then have to filter out those states that match. One way around this would be to store your states as individual documents in their own database. Then your second query would be on the `states` database and look something like this:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "_id": {
      "$gt": null,
      "$in": ["91011","xyz"]
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "_id",
    "_rev"
  ]
}
```

I would lean towards this implementation unless there is some other requirement for saving the states inside the criteria documents.

Finally, there is a way to return `criteria` and `persona` in a single query - similar to a `JOIN` in `SQL`. It would involve adding a `type` field to each document, creating a view, and querying that view with special filters. If you are interested you can learn more here:

https://cloudant.com/blog/sql-joins/